# How can I reduce the amount of times the blue box appears around text?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have just created working code that allows the user to interact with text, when the text; that opens a modal box where text is clicked on and it turns red. The text turning red signals the activation of a checkbox being ticked.

However, every time I interact with the text this blue box surrounds it frequently. The blue box appears when I click on the text and click it again.

I have tried inputting

```
input:focus{
    outline: none;   
}
```

But the blue box problem still repeatedly occurs.

```js
$('a[href="#ex5"]').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).modal({
    escapeClose: false,
    clickClose: false,
    showClose: false,
  });
});
```

```css
.onlyThese {
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label {
  color: red
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- Remember to include jQuery :) -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery Modal -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />

<p><a class="btn" href="#ex5">Sectors </a></p>
<div id="ex5" ; class="modal" ; style="background-color:white">
  <div style="float:left;">
    <input type="checkbox" id="group1">
    <label for="group1" class="onlyThese">Publication </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p style="float:right">
      <a href="#" rel="modal:close" ; class="onlyThese;"> <b>Apply</b> </a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like for the blue box to not appear at all, or reduce how frequently it appears please. I am using google chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
.onlyThese{
cursor:pointer;
-webkit-user-select: none;  
-moz-user-select: none;     
-ms-user-select: none;      
 user-select: none;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In top of your style sheet and use `important` as well

```
:focus{outline: none !important;}
```

If talk about blue background behind the text use this in your `.modal` class

```
.modal{
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: I applied it, but sadly it still produces a blue box. Unless I am not implementing it correctly?

Comment: You mean when i double click, it create blue background behind the text??